# android notification for geolocation

Tags: android, google-maps

I made a android application with multiple Geolocation on Google map (pins)
I would like to send a notification when the user is close to one of these locations.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually fairly easy.  First, set up an application that monitors your location.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android) post will show you more on that.

Once you know your position, you can simply determine if you're within a certain range of it.  To calculate the distance between two points, try the `Location` class:

```
Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results);
```

`results` is a `float[]`, so to return the distance, simply use `float distance = results[0];`.

So, in a nutshell, compile a list of waypoints you want to recognize.  Then, in your GPS monitoring code, regularly check the distance between yourself and the list of points.  If you're within a threshold, say 100m, then send a notification as a `Toast` message or something.

Good luck!